# Bind Json Data to Kendo chart not working MVC 6

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I need to bind my kendo chart with JSON data. It's strange to me because when I copy and paste my JSON results to a JavaScript variable and bind the chart with JavaScript variable it works.

I am using MVC 6 (C#)

**Here is my JSON Results**

[image]

```
[{ "GradeName": "Grade 12", "Accepted": 2, "Rejected": 0, "Pending": 1, "Total": 3 }, { "GradeName": "Grade 10", "Accepted": 1, "Rejected": 1, "Pending": 0, "Total": 2 }, { "GradeName": "Grade 11", "Accepted": 2, "Rejected": 0, "Pending": 0, "Total": 2 }, { "GradeName": "Grade 8", "Accepted": 2, "Rejected": 0, "Pending": 0, "Total": 2 }, { "GradeName": "Grade 9", "Accepted": 0, "Rejected": 0, "Pending": 1, "Total": 1 }]
```

**Here is my chart**

```
<div id="chart"></div>



<script type="text/javascript">

        function createChart() {

            var reportData = @ViewData["JsonData"];
            //var reportData = [{ "GradeName": "Grade 12", "Accepted": 2, "Rejected": 0, "Pending": 1, "Total": 3 }, { "GradeName": "Grade 10", "Accepted": 1, "Rejected": 1, "Pending": 0, "Total": 2 }, { "GradeName": "Grade 11", "Accepted": 2, "Rejected": 0, "Pending": 0, "Total": 2 }, { "GradeName": "Grade 8", "Accepted": 2, "Rejected": 0, "Pending": 0, "Total": 2 }, { "GradeName": "Grade 9", "Accepted": 0, "Rejected": 0, "Pending": 1, "Total": 1 }];


            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                title: {
                    text: "Applications Per Grade",
                    align: "top"
                },
                legend: {
                    visible: true,
                    position: "bottom"
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "column",
                    labels: {
                        visible: false,
                        background: "transparent",
                        value: "Total",
                        position:"bottom"
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    data: reportData,
                    name: "Total Accepted",
                    field: "Accepted",
                    color: "#9BBB59",
                    categoryField: "GradeName"
                },
                {
                    data: reportData,
                    name: "Total Rejected",
                    field: "Rejected",
                    color: "#C0504D",
                    categoryField: "GradeName"
                },
                {
                    data: reportData,
                    name: "Total Pending",
                    field: "Pending",
                    color: "#4F81BD",
                    categoryField: "GradeName"
                }],
                valueAxis: {
                    line: {
                        visible: false
                    },
                    minorGridLines: {
                        visible: true
                    },
                    labels: {
                        rotation: "auto"
                    }
                },
                categoryAxis: {
                    majorGridLines: {
                        visible: false
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
                }

            });
        }

        $(document).ready(createChart);
        $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
    </script>
```

I am assigning `@ViewData["JsonData"]` in my controller

```
string jsonData = GetJson(reportData);

ViewData["JsonData"] = jsonData;
```

**This method is returning Json string**

```
public string GetJson(List<Application> objReportData)
        {
            return (objReportData != null) ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objReportData) : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<Application>());
        }
```

My `Application` class below

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Application
{
//Other properties omitted

        [NotMapped]
        [DataMember]
        public string GradeName { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        [DataMember]
        public int? Accepted { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        [DataMember]
        public int? Rejected { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        [DataMember]
        public int? Pending { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        [DataMember]
        public int? Total { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: where are you getting your reportData from in your controller?  can you print out your reportData in your script and see the output?

Comment: Always check for javascript console errors. I suspect the HTML is being encoded, so the quotation marks are being replaced with "&quot;" in the json string. Try using 'var reportData = @Html.Raw(ViewData["JsonData"])'

Comment: @ryan Thank you so much for your help. Your solution worked for me. You saved me a lot hours. I appreciate the good work that I always receive from you guys. This means the `Html.Raw("...")` method is takes the data is as (without the removing the quotes)?

Comment: @ryan Now how do I mark your comment as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
var reportData = @ViewData["JsonData"];
```

In the javascript is producing an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

MVC is encoding the quotation mark characters (`"`) as `&quot;`

To prevent the `"` from being encoded to `&quot;`, you can use [Html.Raw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
var reportData = @(Html.Raw(ViewData["JsonData"]));
```